# Multiple Regression - Heteroskedasticity? - Is this a linear model?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, residuals, heteroscedasticity

I am analyzing a multiple regression model in SPSS. I am checking whether the requirements for a linear model are met. The last requirement is homoscedasticity. 
In my survey, you can choose between 1-5, so that is a reason why I have parallel lines.

My analyzis Looks like this: [image]

Can I still assume a linear model considering the given plot?

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a heteroskedastic pattern to me. You may need to explore this further. Some directions might include Power Transformations such as the Box-Cox and Box-Tidwell; heteroskedasticity robust standard errors; weighted least squares estimation